# How to add zoom in an image?

Tags: flutter

I need to add zooming to my image, I haven't been able to make it work. If anyone could help me, I would appreciate it.

```dart
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ImageScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final url;

  ImageScreen({
    Key key,
    @required this.url,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: CachedNetworkImage(
        imageUrl: '${this.url}',
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try wrapping your image in the [`InteractiveViewer`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InteractiveViewer-class.html) widget, like this:

```dart
InteractiveViewer(
  child: CachedNetworkImage(
    imageUrl: '${this.url}',
  ),
),
```

This widget provides pan and zoom interactions with its child, check out the Flutter's Widget of the Week video about it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zrn7V3bMJvg).

Please note that to use `CachedNetworkImage` you need to have the [`cached_network_image`](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) plugin installed in you Flutter project.

If you don't have it installed, you can use the [`Image.network`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image-class.html) widget:

```dart
InteractiveViewer(
  child: Image.network(
    '${this.url}',
  ),
),
```

Comment: But how would it look with my code because it marks an error?

Comment: Updated the answer, please make sure you have the `cached_network_image` plugin installed to use the CachedNetworkImage widget, if you don't I added a native Flutter solution.